# Pandas query (eval) filter for many to many relations

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a column of type list:

```
pd.DataFrame([[["item1", "item2"]]], columns=["a"])
     a
0   [item1, item2]
```

and I want to match items from a list:

```
mylist = ["item1", "item3"]
```

without getting **partial** matches.

This works, but gives me partial matches:

```
df.query('a.str.join(" ").str.contains("|".join(@mylist))', engine='python')
```

One way I was thinking is to use whole words with str.contains like it works here:

```
df[df.a.str.contains(r"\bitem1\b")]
```

which works fine, like that, but not in `query()` or `eval()`

when I try to implement it in query like this it doesn't work:

```
df.query('a.str.join(" ").str.contains(r"\bitem1\b")', engine='python') # also use @mylist here
```

I already received an answer on how to do it without query() (`df[[bool(set(x).intersection(mylist)) for x in df['a']]]`), but with my system I'm forced to use query|eval if I want to avoid rewriting a large part of the code.

Comment: What's the problem with using the regex in the query function? Do you get an error?

Comment: @KenSyme I don't get any match for item1, it seems to treat \b as part of the word?

Comment: You can try escaping the \ perhaps? So `.contains(r"\\bitem1\\b")`?

Comment: @KenSyme you are right, I had to escape it, I thought I tried it. thanks

Comment: No problem, I have posted as an answer if you could accept to close off the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should work, just need to escape the backslash:

```
df.query('a.str.join(" ").str.contains(r"\\bitem1\\b")', engine='python')
```